# Column containing mixed dtypes is listed as datetime object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Why is the datatype of my column "Started" containing mixed types listed as `datetime64[ns]`.

```
>>> data = {
...     "Team": ["Borussia Dortmund", "VfL Wolfsburg"],
...     "Coach": ["Peter Bosz", "Andries Jonker"],
...     "Started": ["2017-07-01", dt.datetime(2017, 2, 27)],
...     "Ended": [dt.datetime(2017, 12, 9), dt.datetime(2017, 9, 17)],
... }
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
>>> print(df.dtypes)
Team               object
Coach              object
Started    datetime64[ns]
Ended      datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

I would like to check my columns against datatypes like:

```
from pandas.api.types import is_datetime64_ns_dtype

if not is_datetime64_ns_dtype(df.dtypes["Started"]):
    raise TypeError
```

So the above example should result in a TypeError. The above behaviour gives me headache. Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
In [1646]: if not is_datetime64_ns_dtype(df.Team):
      ...:     raise TypeError
      ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1646-342d73ed413c> in <module>
      1 if not is_datetime64_ns_dtype(df.Team):
----> 2     raise TypeError
      3 

TypeError:
```

For correct column, it should not raise:

```
In [1647]: if not is_datetime64_ns_dtype(df.Started):
      ...:     raise TypeError
      ...:
```

Comment: No, there is no difference. pandas seems to convert the string to a datetime object automatically. If there is a typo in "2017-07-01" (e. g. "2017-07-01a"), the columns' dtype will be ojbect, which is in this case mixed.

Comment: Furthermore, if I just insert dates as string, the dtype will be object, in this case string, as well.